# How to dismiss popover before orientation change on iOS 6?

Tags: ios6, orientation, popover, dismiss

Does anybody has an idea about how could I dismiss a popover **before** orientation change on iOS 6.
I've tried the following:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

But it is not working for me. The popover is still there after the rotation.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutoRotate
```

is not called in my viewController cause it's in a SplitViewController and NavController.
I've read that I can subclass from this containers to forward the shouldAutorotate, but I don't want to do this because of different reasons.
I don't want to dismiss popover after orientationchange (in didRotateFrom...), because it's ugly.

Do you have an idea, how could I dismiss the popover before orientation change on iOS 6?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what possible reason could you have for not wanting to subclass your root view controller?  I'm not sure there's another way to capture the rotation event.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

This will do it once the rotation did change then you can do what you want in the device orientation. Otherwise you need to listen on the view controllers and send the message there.

Comment: Hi Darren, As I've said I need to get notified before orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```